# Is it possible to build an assembly, and force it to a specific build #?

Tags: c#, assemblies

Is it possible to build an assembly, and force it to a specific build #?

Comment: what do u mean by build#? the version number of the assembly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure. Just set the last digit of

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

to the build number you want.

Comment: In your project's AssemblyInfo.cs

Comment: @Jason - I could be wrong but I believe it can be on any source file, really.

Comment: @ocdecio:  It can be anywhere...but AssemblyInfo.cs is probably the best place for it...

Comment: @Jason - yes, that is reasonable if you want to follow Visual Studio's defaults.

Answer (score 1):

Just apply the `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("A.B.C.D")]` attribute the this is usually in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file, though can be in any code file. The last portion of the version `(A.B.C.D)` - `D`, is the build number.